# It works on Debian 5.0 but it cause segmentation fault on ubuntu 11.10

Tags: java, c, sockets, segmentation-fault

I hope I'll not get a tonne of messages that's dump question. I really tried to find out where is the problem but I don't know why this works on one linux and cause segmentation fault on other linux. So when I run it on computer number one it works fine but when I run it on comuputer number two it cause segmentation fault and I get message SIGSEGV.
**Computer number one has config:** 
cat /etc/issue get: Debian GNU/Linux 5.0 
 
uname -a get: Linux eryx2 2.6.34.4servgs #3 SMP Sun Aug 22 00:38:18 CEST 2010 i686 GNU/Linux 
**Computer number two has config:** 
cat /etc/issue get: Ubuntu 11.10 
uname -a get: Linux ubuntu 3.0.0-15-generic #25-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jan 2 17:44:42 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

I enclose code of my application.
1.I run the server - ok
2.I run the client 
3.Client sends message to server
4.Server try to recieve message from server and it cause segmentation fault

But this problem is only on Ubuntu when I run it on first computer i've specified it works ok.

I also build resp. compile source codes on each system.

server:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/un.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int sendMessage(char* msg, int socket){
    int length = strlen(msg);
    int ret;

    ret = write(socket, msg, length);
    return ret;
}

int readLine(void *vptr, size_t maxlen, int sockd) {
    int n, rc;
    char    c, *buffer;

    buffer = vptr;

    for ( n = 1; n < maxlen; n++ ) {

        if ( (rc = read(sockd, &c, 1)) == 1 ) {
            *buffer++ = c;
            if ( c == '\n' )
                break;
        }
        else if ( rc == 0 ) {
            if ( n == 1 )
                return 0;
            else
                break;
        }

    }

    *buffer = 0;
    return n;
}

int main()
{
    int server_sockfd, client_sockfd;
    int server_len, client_len;
    struct sockaddr_in server_address;
    struct sockaddr_in client_address;


    server_sockfd = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0 );
    server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr( "127.0.0.1" );
    server_address.sin_port = htons( 10000 );

    server_len = sizeof( server_address );

        if( bind( server_sockfd, ( struct sockaddr *)&server_address, server_len ) != 0 )
        {
                perror("oops: server-tcp-single");
                exit( 1 );
        }

    listen( server_sockfd, 5 );

    signal( SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN );

    while( 1 )
    {
        char ch;

        printf( "server wait...\n" );

        client_len = sizeof( client_address );
        client_sockfd = accept( server_sockfd, ( struct sockaddr *)&client_address, &client_len );

        printf( "Connected client from %s\n", inet_ntoa( client_address.sin_addr) );

        if( fork() == 0 )
        {
            char retezec[20];
            readLine(retezec, 20, client_sockfd);

            printf( "Klient sent : %s\n", retezec );
            printf( "Server sends : %s\n", retezec );
            sendMessage(retezec, client_sockfd);
                close( client_sockfd );

            exit (0 );
        }
        else
            close( client_sockfd );

    }
}
```

client

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class clientTCP
{
    private static PrintWriter pw;
    private static BufferedReader br;

    private static void sendToServer(String msg) {
          try 
      {
                pw.println(msg);
                //System.out.println(msg);
                System.out.println("Klient poslal: " + msg);
            } 
      catch (Exception e)
      {
            // System.out.println("e.Message");
          }
    }

    private static String recieveFromServer() {
        String msg = "Chyba";
        try
      {
                msg = br.readLine();
              //System.out.println(msg);
              System.out.println("Klient prijal: " + msg);
        }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
                System.out.println("Selhalo prijimani zpravy zpravy!");
                //System.out.println(e.Message);
       }
       return msg;
    }

 public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception
 {
  Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 10000);
  InetAddress adresa = socket.getInetAddress();
  System.out.print("Pripojuju se na : "+adresa.getHostAddress()+" se jmenem : "+adresa.getHostName()+"\n" );

  pw = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
    br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
  sendToServer("ahoj\n");
  String message = recieveFromServer(); 
  //System.out.println("Message Received: " + message);
  socket.close();
 }
}
```

Thanks.

Edited java and gcc versions:

**first computer Debian:**
java version "1.6.0_20"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_20-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 16.3-b01, mixed mode)

gcc version 4.3.2 (Debian 4.3.2-1.1)

**second computer Ubuntu**
java version "1.6.0_26"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_26-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.1-b02, mixed mode)

gcc version 4.6.1 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.1-9ubuntu3)

**Edit: Problem solved trought dicusion and googling** 

so I'm adding changes it may help somebody with similar problem. 
There were couple problems in Server:
instead of

```
int server_len, client_len;
```

I should use 
    `socklen_t str_len, client_len;`

Then instead of this (which was the cause of segmentation fault):
 printf( "Connected client from %s\n", inet_ntoa( client_address.sin_addr) );
I should use function inet_ntop cause I found that inet_ntoa deprecated.
Cause of seg fault was that I use %s so as arg of printf is expected char *
this is the better solution and I hope also clear.

```
char str[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
inet_ntop(AF_INET,&(client_address.sin_addr), str, INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
printf( "Connected client from %s\n", str );
```

I didn't know what with this question, cause I get good answers trouht comments and my work.
So I at least added fixes needed to solve problem.

Comment: What are the versions of Java and gcc on both machines?

Comment: Please do yourself a favor and fix all the problems that compiling the C code with `-Wall` points out.

Comment: Can you tell us where the seg fault occurs?  What do you see when you load the core dump with a debugger?

Comment: I added java and gcc versions to the end of my question.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I tryed to write it in 4rd paragraph. It must be somewhere in Server when call my function readLine(...). I print there messages. Connection works, then I call readLine and seg. fault occurs. Did I answer your question?

Comment: @Mat Sorry -Wall? What is it? I never used it before. 
But I found the mistake which I solved before. When I comment this it works.
 printf( "Connected client from %s\n", inet_ntoa( client_address.sin_addr) );
So that is probably cause seg fault.
I printf need (char *), (char *) inet_ntoa(...) cause another problem ... But it works on first computer without problem .. 
Its anohter question but, can I change this to have it ok?
 printf( "Connected client from %s\n", inet_ntoa( client_address.sin_addr) );

Comment: `-Wall` is the compiler flag that tells GCC to output warnings. One of the problems with your code that the warnings highlight is the bug you "fixed". Fix the other ones, and remove that "fix" you did with that cast, it's not good.

Comment: @Mat Thanks -Wall really helped. I went over all warnings and made it clear without warnings and now it works without any problems :)
I didn't know that warnings could cause problem like seg fault. But it's nice to have the code clear :)

Comment: The warnings about missing declarations for functions can lead to very bad things happening (you _must_ fix those by including the right headers). Problems with format strings very often lead to undefined behavior (hence crashes, strange behavior, or, unfortunately, nothing visible like on your machine where it worked).

Comment: Its good to know:) It's my first "bigger" work in C.
I'm also not so long at stackoverflow so I didn't know what to do know with this question now ... problem was solved so I at least add the solution to the end to this question. It may help somebody (or not).

Answer (score 1):

I would make sure you always set `\0` at the end.  You have a `return 0` which the caller ignores.  This means if the char[] doesn't have a `\0` byte already in array you could get a seg fault.

Answer (score 0):

i meet the same problem. it's because you fail to include

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
```

which result a implicit declare whille compiling the code. the implicit declare method always return an int instread of other types(like char *).

seg fault when

> printf( "Connected client from %s\n", inet_ntoa(
>   client_address.sin_addr) );

because the inet_ntoa() returns a address and was converted to 0xffffffffef7dde20, which is out of bounds. the inet_ntoa's return value was treated as a 32 bit int.

you fix your problem with inet_ntop, not because of inet_ntop is the solution, if you use the return value of inet_ntop as the argument of printf, you still get a segment fault.